# Using formulas, extract an OS version number from a variable string

Tags: excel, parsing, substring, excel-formula

I have a list of OSs running on a bunch of servers in my workplace. The string giving the OS can be of many formats. Here are some samples:

- AIX 5.1
- VMware ESX Server 3.5.0 build-110268
- Linux Linux 2.6.X Linux
- Red Hat Enterprise AS 4 (2.6.9-78.0.13.ELlargesmp)
- Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 2000 Advanced Server
- Microsoft Windows XP Win2008R2 6.1.7601

There are 180 unique strings in all (and >10,000 servers).

My boss is asking for a formula that will extract the OS type and version from each string. I have made one for the OS type that works reliably by looking up a table with ten entries. But the version formula is tougher, as the format of the version is dependent on the type of OS, and even then there can be multiple formats per OS type.

As far as I'm concerned you would need a table containing 180 rows, with the strings in COL A, the versions in COL B, and then do a Vlookup on the string. However, he is demanding the version be extracted from the string, using only excel formulas, no vba.

I've pretty much given up at this point, so I'm throwing it out to this website. Anyone know if this can be done, and how?

Comment: It would probably be easier to handle with VBA but some answers are really good (even if they probably can't handle as many cases as VBA would)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a so-called array formula, which is capable of doing calculations on a whole array in one go. When entering an array formula, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end, as opposed to just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The screenshot below shows the different columns and the formula to use. Enter the formula in cell `E1` first (and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm). Then copy down to the other cells in column `E` by selecting `E1` and dragging the right-bottom corner all the way down.

Column `A` contains the 180 names of your OS-es. Column `B` contains their version numbers. Column `D` contains the >10,000 strings to look up. Column `E` contains the >10,000 corresponding looked-up version numbers.

The formula used in column `E` is

```
=IF(MAX(COUNTIF(D1,$A$1:$A$6)),OFFSET($B$1,MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$6)*COUNTIF(D1,$A$1:$A$6))-1,0),"Not Found")
```

The `D1` in this formula will change with the row number. In your case, `$A$6` should of course be replaced with `$A$180` to do the lookup for all your 180 OS names. I am not sure what happens to the performance when you increase the number of items to the scale you asked for, so I suggest doing this step by step, increasing the number of items slowly...

If this works for you, I can explain in some more detail how the formula works, if you need any help there.

Note: if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm as an array-formula, Excel will show curly brackets around it. You have to use this key-combination every time when you change the formula as well.

[image: Screenshot of Excel sheet illustrating formula to use]

Comment: Thanks Reinier. This is about as close as you can get.

Comment: You are welcome. Just out of curiosity: to me this looks like it exactly answers your question, but your comment implies it does not. What is missing?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt at it:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".", A1))), "Cannot find version number", IF(NOT(OR(MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "1", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "2", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "3", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "4", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "5", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "6", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "7", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "8", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1) = "9")), IF(NOT(ISERROR(MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 1, SEARCH(" ", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1), LEN(A1)))))), MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 1, SEARCH(" ", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1), LEN(A1)))), MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 1, LEN(A1))),  IF(NOT(ISERROR(MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, SEARCH(" ", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1), LEN(A1)))))), MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, 1 + SEARCH(" ", MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1), LEN(A1)))), MID(A1, SEARCH(".", A1) - 2, LEN(A1)))))
```

The benefit of this (complicated) formula is that it works for versions greater than 9.  For example, if the whole text were "Ubuntu Linux 13.5.3," it would print out "13.5.3."  Hope this helps!

Edit: I should add that my formula assumes that there will be no operating systems at version 100 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

I had some time to spare and decided to try this as a fun challenge. It works, but it's extremely sensitive to any variation. It outputs the correct version number for all cases you have submitted here, though.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",B2,1)),"Cannot find version number",IF(ISERROR(FIND("(",B2,1)), MID(B2, FIND(".",B2, 1)-1, IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ", B2, FIND(".", B2, 1))), LEN(B2) + 1, FIND(" ", B2, FIND(".", B2, 1))) - FIND(".", B2, 1) + 1),MID(B2,FIND("(",B2,1)+1,FIND(")",B2,1)-FIND("(",B2,1)-1)))
```

If there is any error in the formula it may be because I had to translate functions. Let me know and I will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Reinier's answer is great also, but I have been taught a new way which works well enough my my stubborn boss's satisfaction :) . It requires a lookup table with around 35 values (much better than having an entry for all 180 unique strings, which was my only solution before this). The formula it uses is:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15, SEARCH('Lookup Tables'!$A$2:$A$36, $A2), 'Lookup Tables'!$B$2:$B$36), "")
```

It does not need to be entered as an array formula. On the sheet 'Lookup Tables', column A holds a list of lookup terms, and column B holds the version numbers associated with those terms. A lookup term may include wildcards. For example:

> Win*2003

Will match any string with Win and 2003 in it, so long as the former precedes the latter. You do not need to include wildcards on the left and right of the string, the formula does this for you. Strangely enough, if the string matches two entries in the list, the bottom one will take precedence, not the top.

Of course, you first have to go through the list of 180 strings and figure out what lookup strings to include.

The value $A2 in the formula represents the cell containing the OS string. 2^15 is an arbitrary large number. I can't explain exactly how the formula works, but it does.